# Selecting a status from several included entities in mvc 4 using entity framework 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

How do I select the status name of "barn doors open" in linq when using the include statement?

```
// GET: /Cowbow/Farm/
public ActionResult IndexNew()
{
    var barns = dbFarm.Barn.Include(b => b.Dog).Include(b => b.Cat).Include(b => b.Pig).Include(b => b.Cow).Include(b => b.Chicken).Include(b => b.Feed);
    // return View(barns.ToList()); // normal scaffold generated return
 return View(barns.Where(b => b.Statuses.Where(s => s.statusName == "barn doors open")).AsEnumerable().ToList());

}
```

Barn also has a Status.StatusName field that has a foreign key relationship to the barnid.  It also has two possible status names, "barn doors open", and "barn doors closed", and a date field when the status occurred and an id field.  I can only add farm animals when barn doors are open.

Not sure if this is correct idea since there can be multiple statuses per barn.

How do I list out only those barns where the last status that occurred by date where the StatusName is "barn doors open"?

I tried to tack on a .FirstDefault but I want all Barns that contain "barns doors open" not just the first barn.

Comment: Where the `barns` comes from...? What is the `accounts` and where it used...?

Comment: Your not supposed to see that. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand you, in one certain moment your barn may have only one status (open or closed). So you don't need many-to-many ralation. Just write:

```
return View(barns.Where(a => a.Status.statusName == "barn doors open").AsEnumerable().ToList());
```

Comment: return View(barns.Where(b => b.Statuses.Contains(new Status { StatusName = "barn doors open" })).ToList());

Comment: Because I want to keep track of every time my Barn door opens or closes by a datetime stamp.

Comment: @CyberSluethOmega Ok. I can't comment, because I never use such approach before. If it works give me know:) It's interesting

Comment: At any given instant the barn only has one status.  But I want to store all of the the status changes on the barn with a date time stamp.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this...? :

```
return View(barns
    .Where(b => b.Statuses
        .Where(s => s.statusName == "barn doors open" && 
            s.TimeStap == b.Statuses.Max(st => st.TimeStamp))
    .AsEnumerable().ToList());
```

You also don't need to call `.AsEnumerable()`.